# indices in MaxPool2d in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pooling

I am studying the documentation at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html.

In the parameters section, it states

> return_indices – if True, will return the max indices along with the outputs. Useful for torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d later

Could someone explain to me what *max indices* mean here? I believe it is the indices corresponding to the maximal value. If the maximal value is unique, does that mean only 1 index will be returned?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already know how max pooling works.
Then, let's print some results to get more insights.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, return_indices=True)
input = torch.zeros(1, 1, 4, 4)
input[..., 0, 1] = input[..., 1, 3] = input[..., 2, 2] = input[..., 3, 0] = 1. 
print(input)
```

###### output

```
tensor([[[[0., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1.],
          [0., 0., 1., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.]]]])
```

```py
output, indices = pool(input)
print(output)
```

###### output

```
tensor([[[[1., 1.],
          [1., 1.]]]])
```

```py
print(indices)
```

###### output

```
tensor([[[[ 1,  7],
          [12, 10]]]])
```

If you `stretch` the input tensor and make it 1d, you can see that `indices` contains the positions of each `1` value (the maximum for each window of MaxPool2d). As written in the documentation of `torch.nn.MaxPool2d`, `indices` is required for the `torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d` [module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d.html#torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d):

> MaxUnpool2d takes in as input the output of MaxPool2d including the indices of the maximal values and computes a partial inverse in which all non-maximal values are set to zero.

Comment: Got it, I think I undertand now. What if the maximal value in a pooling window isn't unique? Does it just arbtrarily choose an index?

Comment: You can easily test it with the code above. My guess is that it will take the first occurrence in the window!